# is a 555 timer flyback driver lethal?

Tags: current, 555, flyback, shock

i have always heard on websites that the 555 timer flyback driver is not lethal. i know that the common ZVS driver is lethal but would the 555 flyback driver be able to deliver a deliver a lethal shock? of course i wouldn't put it on my tongue and i would keep one hand on the power switch) but many websites say it is not lethal as long as you don't drive it to hard (as in keep a low input voltage to the driver) 
the one i want to build: https://sites.google.com/site/uzzors2k/flybacktransformer . is the first one (the "simple" 555 timer flyback driver) and i would use a dc flyback from a CRT TV (not a monitor) and would have an input voltage of 12v.
thanks.

Comment: Most flybacks are high voltage, but low current. This means they aren't very dangerous. You could build a really powerful flyback with enough power to be lethal, but most flybacks aren't designed for it.

Comment: Safety is discussed in the last paragraph of the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

a 555 by itself can only put a few watts into the output, you can't get a lethal current that way.

but a 555 driving a power transistor can do tens or hundereds of watts, and that's enough to kill.

not only is the secondary voltage dangerous, the primary can develop hundereds of volts when the transistor turns off.